# Dual Inner Join Query taking forever to run

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

i would like to runa a query to get some simple stats on our database but it returns the following error. can someone advise me on how to fix it?

query =

```
SELECT     tblSchemes.Clientid, count(clientid), count(insscheme)
FROM       tblSchemes
 INNER JOIN tblclaims_liberty ON tblClaims_liberty.AgentCode = tblSchemes.ClientID 
 INNER JOIN tblPolicys_liberty ON tblSchemes.Scheme = tblPolicys_liberty.InsScheme
GROUP BY tblSchemes.Clientid
```

Error returned =

```
Msg 8115, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Arithmetic overflow error converting expression to data type int.
```

Many thanks in advance.

Adam

Comment: what is the data type of clientid & insscheme?

Comment: What types are the 4 fields you are joining on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be exceeding the limit on COUNT, which returns an integer. Try using [COUNT_BIG](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190317.aspx) instead as it returns a bigint.

Comment: thankyou, that worked, but i've obviously got something wrong.. its telling me we have 10258155655 claims when i know for a fact there are only a fraction of that number..

Comment: @adam-mcc, You may not be joining enough fields which results in a cartesian product somewhere

Comment: @adam-mcc, it will return the same number because you are doing an inner join so both of those will not be null, thus counting the same.

Comment: basically, i have three tables, one with policys, one with claims and the other with a list of the scheme names to link them together, i'd like to retrieve a list of the schemenames and then the total number of policys and claims for each. i still have a lot to learn about SQL..

Answer (score 1):

I would suspect a data type mismatch between some of the join fields. It is trying to convert something and that seems the most logical place.